# Error: Network Error from polyfills.js

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I am running an Ionic 3.9.0 app (Angular 5) on my ios device and getting the following error after some seconds:

[image]

This is occurring in Safari when inspecting the index.html.

This causes an Observable on Firebase (through AngularFire2) to stop working...

I cannot manage to track the error and understand where it comes from.

How could I obtain more details and understand it?

Any help would much appreciated.